# How to do Automation Testing on Openerp or Odoo?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, odoo

I want to test odoo modules with the help of Automation Testing Tools.

How can i do that, pls give me suggestion.

Is there any automation testing tool available for odoo project testing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use selenium testing tool & write a script in it
Also u can do YML testing by writing YML script in test files of an OpenERP or ODOO

**

https://doc.odoo.com/6.0/developer/5_16_data_serialization/yaml_serialization/

Answer (score 1):

You can try open source tools like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Additionally, I found this slideshare presentation,

http://www.slideshare.net/openobject/how-to-develop-automated-tests

...which talks about [run-bot](https://github.com/odoo/odoo-extra).